# Unterminated string constant javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

```
onclick="var searchb = jQuery('#'+searchBoxLinkId).value; 
var searchlink= window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname+'/Dave2/Pages/FAQSearch.aspx?category='+category+'&k='+searchb;
window.location = searchlink;" href="javascript: {}">
```

I have added this line of code to my javascript/html but it gives me the error `Unterminated string constant` however I cannot see where the problem is.
I have to do it this way as I am doing something in sharepoint and it seems like this way is the only way it will work

Comment: you have some heavy typos in your code, check the double quotes

Comment: Look at the colors in the code above, and see if you can't spot it, it has something to do with the quotes.

Comment: because I am doing this in a sharepoint display template and as I have created my own function, it won't be defined in the ctx, so can't be run by just putting the function name

Comment: if you know how to do this in sharepoint please tell me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not set the `searchBoxLinkId` and `category` variables.

We assume some existing HTML (such as the snippet below) will set the two variables. In the code below, you can enter some variable into `input` and `category` is set to `11111`. When you click on a tag, you redirect to that address.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var category=11111;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="searchBoxLinkId"/>
    <a onclick="var searchb = jQuery('#searchBoxLinkId').val(); var searchlink= window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname+'/Dave2/Pages/FAQSearch.aspx?category='+category+'&k='+searchb;window.location.href = searchlink;" href="#">eee</a>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use matching pairs of single or double quotation marks. Double quotation marks can be contained within strings surrounded by single quotation marks, and single quotation marks can be contained within strings surrounded by double quotation marks.

Comment: added some example it will be better for OP to understand

Comment: Actually rewriting the OP's code with the correct fixes would be best